# How create scrollable cell in dataGridview in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar, cell

I in my C# Windows Forms project, I have `DataGridView` with 6 columns. But the length of the textual information inside one of the columns is very long and sometimes reaches 5 or 6 lines.

How can I place a scroll bar only for the cells of this column if the number of lines is high and exceeds the height of the cell?

For example, for the screenshot shown here, I have written 7 lines and scroll bar should be placed in this cell.

[image]

Should I override the gridview? If yes - how can I do this?

I do not find any solution. Please help

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/controls-with-built-in-owner-drawing-support?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you very much. Your hint helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

DataGridView do not use controls for cells in view mode, so it doesn't support scrollbars for cell in view mode. Custom paint also doesn't help. The closest thing to what you are looking for is: enabling enabling multiline scrollable editor for the cell in edit edit mode, and setting the edit mode to EditOnEnter, so that when you click on the cell, it shows the scrollbars. You can also keep the data read-only easily, if needed.

[image]

**Example - Multi line cell with vertical scroll bar**

Use the following code in the Load event handler of a form having a DataGridView named dataGridView1 to see what I've shown in the screenshot in action:

```
//Increase the height of row, to show more lines by default
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height *= 2;

//Load data
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("عنوان");
dt.Columns.Add("دسته بندی ها");
dt.Rows.Add("دسته بندی یک",
    "زیر مجموعه یک" + Environment.NewLine +
    "زیر مجموعه دو" + Environment.NewLine +
    "زیر مجموعه سه" + Environment.NewLine +
    "زیر مجموعه چهار" + Environment.NewLine +
    "زیر مجموعه پنج");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

//Goes to edit mode on enter to show scrollbar once you click on the cell 
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;

//Increase the width of column to open some space for vertical scrollbar
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width += SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;

//Support multiline data for the cell
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

//If you want to keep the data read-only
dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;

//Support multiline text and vertical scrrollbar 
dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += (obj, args) =>
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        var txt = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)args.Control;
        txt.Multiline = true;
        txt.WordWrap = false;
        txt.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;

        //If you want to keep the data read-only
        txt.ReadOnly = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Sadegh, Do you forget to come back and check/accept the answer, or do you have any issue applying the solution?